# FTP client logged out immediately after logging in. Pure-ftp/Cpanel/WHM

Tags: ftp, cpanel, whm, pure-ftpd

I'm trying to enable ftp on a cpanel/whm server but users are having trouble logging in. Ports are open and I can see connections are reaching the server because they are logged. However the clients show a timeout and the logs just say that the user is immediately logged out after.

Could someone explain this and provide a solution for me? The server is running Cloudlinux, Litespeed and CageFS however I've tested disabling each one for a user to no avail.

[image: screenshot]

```
Error log from filezilla:
Status:         Connecting to [ip address]:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Logged in
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode ([ip address stuff])
Command:    MLSD
Error:          The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out
Error:          Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem I referred to https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Enable+FTP+Passive+Mode
and simply enabled port range 49152 - 65534 through my firewall.